# How to prevent "evil maid" attacks? How to move /boot to a USB pendrive?

Tags: linux, boot, usb-flash-drive, disk-encryption

Apparently using full-disk encryption is not enough to secure a computer, because the /boot partition is not encrypted, and could be modified to include a keylogger.

I have read about different counter-measures, but the only one that didn't sound too complicated and I actually understood was moving the /boot partition to a USB pendrive which I should carry with me all the time and use it to boot.

So how do I do that? I'm using Fedora 17, 18, and Ubuntu 12.04.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious to what kinda threat you believe you'd face to need to have that kind of security

Comment: @JourneymanGeek With the popularization of cryptocurrencies, we are gonna need to raise the bar in security sooner or later: [Tale of an evil roommate](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1fqlhd/tale_of_an_evil_roommate/). Specialized hardware might end up being the solution, but in the meantime we have to find other ways to protect people.

Answer (score 0):

Moving /boot to a removable medium works **as long as you do not forget to carry it with you when you leave the computer**.  I think most people will forget this at least a few times.

A better protection against an *evil maid` would be:

- A BIOS password
- A required smartcard which also opens the doors (in other words, if you forget the card you can not leave the office).
- Good physical security (optionally tying in the pass cards).
- And ofc. not having sensitive data at all on the computer.